# trying to set nginx with https configuration returns Invalid Host header

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I'm trying to configure nginx with https so i can browse into it (www.oidctest.com -- (configured to localhost at hosts file) and it will redirect to my application resides at: www.oidctest.com:3000

my nginx configuration is:

```
    server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
        server_name     www.oidctest.com;
        return 301 http://$server_name:3000$request_uri;
        # certs sent to the client in SERVER HELLO are concatenated in
        ssl_certificate
        ssl_certificate /nginx-1.14.1/conf/server.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /nginx-1.14.1/conf/server.key;
        ssl_session_timeout 1d;
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
        ssl_session_tickets off;

        # Diffie-Hellman parameter for DHE ciphersuites, recommended 2048 bits
        #ssl_dhparam /path/to/dhparam.pem;

        # intermediate configuration. tweak to your needs.
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE....HA:!DSS';
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        # HSTS (ngx_http_headers_module is required) (15768000 seconds = 6 months)
        #add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;

        # OCSP Stapling ---
        # fetch OCSP records from URL in ssl_certificate and cache them
        ssl_stapling on;
        ssl_stapling_verify on;

        ## verify chain of trust of OCSP response using Root CA and Intermediate certs
        #ssl_trusted_certificate /path/to/root_CA_cert_plus_intermediates;

        resolver 8.8.8.8;

         location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
        }
    }
}
```

but when i'm browsing into "www.oidctest.com" i get: "Invalid Host header"

can u suggest for solution?

Answer (score 0):

in the nginx.conf, I would replace

```
proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
```

With

```
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
```

But more importantly, the error is related to you ReactJS app (I guess it is one of those?). You can add allowedHosts under devServer in your webpack.config.js:

```
devServer: {
  compress: true,
  inline: true,
  port: '8080',
  allowedHosts: [
      '.amazonaws.com'
  ]
},
```

Comment: Why would you replace localhost with 127.0.0.1 ?

Comment: @Sagar, any domain name in nginx.conf needs resolving, which needs additional configuration (`resolver` directive). I don't see any reason using `localhost` if you know its IP is `127.0.0.1`